# Using JTextPane to display HTML, is SVG supported?

Tags: java, swing, svg

I'm trying to embed svg images in the HTML, they don't appear to be working with the  or  tag.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing support only a subset of HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

[JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html) has better support as [shown here](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1193176134001).

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
</head>

<body>
    <object width="700" height="200" data="fileName.svg"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title></title>

</head>

<body>
 <object width="700" height="200" data="fileName.svg"></object>
</body>
</html>